# Grep command with multiple conditions

Tags: linux, shell-script

Is it possible somehow to combine

```
egrep 'version:|hostname:' File.log
```

and

```
egrep -A1 'error' File.log
```

into one `egrep` so they would be executed in the same time?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to show us a small sample input file `File.log` and the desired output you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I suppose you don't mean just `grep -E -A1 'error|version:|hostname:' File.log`? Is it that you want the line after the match displayed only for lines matching "error"?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you want to print all lines that contain `version:`, `hostname:` or `error`, and also a single line after a line matching `error`.

You can't do that with grep, but you can do it relatively simply in AWK. Here, the `p` variable acts as a counter of lines to print, and the others are just printed after matching the patterns:

```
% cat foo.txt
hostname: foo
version: 1.2.3
blah
error:
   some error description
bleh
blih
```

```
% awk '/version:|hostname:/ {print; next} p {p--; print; next} /error/ {p=1; print} ' foo.txt
hostname: foo
version: 1.2.3
error:
   some error description
```

---

Unlike `grep -A1`, the above doesn't trigger printing the next line from a match that already is on the "next line". To do that, we'll have to rearrange the conditions a bit:

```
% awk '/error/ {p=2} p {p--; print; next} /version:|hostname:/ {print}' foo.txt
hostname: foo
version: 1.2.3
error:
   some error description
bleh
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I needed.